# Submitting and Handing Dynamic Form

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, dynamic

I have a dynamic form as in this image . As you can see in second row + button allows to add more rows . There are different type of email subscriptions here . I need to be able to save this form and know what type of subject and how many emails were subscribed and frequency for each type .People can add many rows and can delete any random one . How do I process that in backend ? Here is sample of what form may look like .

As you can see I can have say 5 sub-rows for biology and user may than delete 2nd row and add a 6th row . How do I figure that out based on form and delete it on backend and add new row ? I am using java(jsp) and mysql .

Comment: What language or framework do you use at your backend?

Comment: No JSF, Struts or any other framework?

Comment: Please consider using JSF and something like [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/), [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) or some other component library.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that either you want to do a lot of scripting on client side (jQuery, Prototype) or use [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/). In your situation I would use GWT as it's easier to develop in Java and not worry about browser compatibility in such simple case.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to use JSF and something like [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/). There are excellent examples like [in cell data table editing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableEditing.jsf). It will also offer you lots of [Ajax](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/pprPartialTree.jsf) possibilities without the need to code any Javascript.

If you are want to stay away from JSF I can also recommend [Playframework](http://www.playframework.org/). It also comes with excellent examples like [a classic CRUD application, backed by a JDBC database](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/Samples).